# parameterization of surface of revolution?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

parameterization of surface of revolution formed by revolving the $x=\cosh z$ around z axis ,
i thought the it as $$x=\cosh z \cos \theta ,y=\cosh z \sin \theta ,z=z$$
Hence the surface can be parameterized by $(z,\theta )$ .

I want to know that is it  right .

Comment: That's correct.